# Load image from external jar ,classpath at runtime

Tags: java, jar, classloader

i have an application depends on plugins
i have a case when i want to load an image from one of my plugins jar

the only way to load the image is

```
ClassFromPLugin.class.getClassLoader().getResource("image.png");
```

how can i load the image without using the ClassFromPlugin 
but use current Component class who need that image

i am loading my jars at runtime , 
and this specific component who want to load the image 
don't know where it came from , he just get the image location

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must use the ClassLoader with which you loaded the jar containing the image.

Comment: how can i do so 
i am using a new class loader each time i am detecting an plugin 

      URL jarfile = new URL("jar", "", "file:"  + jarFile.getAbsolutePath() + "!/");
      URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { jarfile });

i dont know which one is the correct one

Comment: i extends the URLClassLoader ,and make a public method for
    public void addURL(URL url) 
so each time instead of creating a new ClassLoader for jar 
i am using the same classLoader 

public class TestClassLoader extends URLClassLoader{

  public TestClassLoader() {
    super(new URL[0]);
  }

  public void addURL(URL url){
    super.addURL(url);
  }
}

is this a correct way to do it ?
is there disadvantage for this way 
i can guess there must be a reason why sun always creating a new class loader

Comment: Note that you can also chain the ClassLoaders

Comment: why sun didnt make it that way 
there is a reason for that ,
is that a bad implementation ?